# Python Excel parsing data with xlrd

Tags: python, excel, types, xls, xlrd

Fairly simple; I've got the data I want out of the excel file, but can't seem to find anything inside the [XLRD readme](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html) that explains how to go from this:

```
xldate:40397.007905092592
number:10000.0
text:u'No'
number:0.1203
number:0.096000000000000002
number:0.126
```

to their respective python datatypes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you tried the documentation help --> [date_function](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html#xldate.xldate_as_tuple-function)

Comment: The issue was that i hadn't bothered to take the value out of the cell class, so it was just printing the cell object. Marking as answered anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and used the following as a last resort:

```
def numobj2fl(p):
    return float(str(p).split(":")[1])
```

for converting the 'number object' to float.